# How to get all heading names retrieved by cheerio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I have following code which is intended to output all heading names retrieved by cheerio from a specific html page.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const rp = require('request-promise');

async function run() {
  const options = {
    uri: '<SOME_URL>',
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    transform: (body) => {
      return cheerio.load(body);
    }
  }
  try{
    const $ = await rp(options);
    $("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6").map(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
}

run();
```

However the output from above code is something like

```
0
1
2
...
```

I tried change `console.log(e)` to `e.attr('name')`, then it returns me an error

> TypeError: e.attr is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `$().map` is giving you the index as the first parameter and the element as the second.

I guess you need this:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const rp = require('request-promise');

const uri = 'http://www.somesite.com';
async function run() {
  const options = {
    uri,
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    transform: (body) => {
      return cheerio.load(body);
    }
  }
  try{
    const $ = await rp(options);
    $("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6").map((_,element) => {
      console.log($(element).html()) // just output the content too to check everything is alright
      console.log(element.name);
    });
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
}

run();
```